# Count null columns in each row - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to count number of columns that are null or = '' in each row in SQL. And group by `Row_ID`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Row_ID, COUNT(*) AS 'cnt_blankCol'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    table_catalog = 'db'
    AND table_name = 'tblName'
    AND COLUMNS IS NULL OR COLUMNS = '' 
GROUP BY 
    Row_ID
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. A column name cannot be either NULL or an empty string. And what is Row_ID?

Comment: please fix the format of the code

Comment: I mean column value.
I want to get blank fields in each row. But don't want to write name of all columns.

Comment: `AND` takes precedence over `OR`. If you wanted rows where some `columns` is null or emtpy, you should have written `AND (COLUMNS IS NULL OR COLUMNS = '')`. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` has no such field though - it returns the column names, not the contents

Comment: @NavidAbyazi if you want to check row values, you'll have to query all tables. If you want to find *nullable* columns, you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos You are right about putting parentheses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Information_Schema tables are metadata tables that contain information about the database objects them selves, it does not contain the actual data from the tables, and it does not contain data aggregates per object.

This can not be done querying information_schema. Perhaps the Op can update the question and give a scenario of the goal of the question.

Comment: Could you describe more?

Comment: Evey table is its own snowflake, the information schema tables are there to tell you about the table definition, it does not contain the data in the table, nor does it collect analytical characteristics in this fashion.